# Whether to create Round Robin or Hash in synapse dedicated sql pool

Tags: azure-synapse

I will have to create a table with columns (Time24Hr, Viewers, Time12Hr). This gives live information on how many users visited the website by the minute. Here is the sample information -

{"Time24Hr":"2022-08-01T00:00:00","viewers":8009,"Time12Hr":"8/1/2022 12:00:00 AM"}
{"Time24Hr":"2022-08-01T00:01:00","viewers":7737,"Time12Hr":"8/1/2022 12:01:00 AM"}
{"Time24Hr":"2022-08-01T00:02:00","viewers":7663,"Time12Hr":"8/1/2022 12:02:00 AM"}
{"Time24Hr":"2022-08-01T00:03:00","viewers":7841,"Time12Hr":"8/1/2022 12:03:00 AM"}
.
.
.
.

Volume Expected: Per day - 1440 Records, Each Month - 43800, Each Year - 525600

My question is -

1. Just going with the above columns, I don't find a potential candidate for Hash. Hence what could be the best distribution to use here, Round Robin / Hash?
2. On the reporting side, the Time value out of the Time24Hr/Time12Hr fields will be used most frequently between current and previous days/months to identify the viewer pattern. Hence I was planning to create a new Time column to split the time from Time24Hr/Time12Hr fields and have this newly created Time column as the Hash value and create the table as Hash distribution. What are your thoughts? Is this a good decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree. With those initial 3 columns you don’t have a good candidate for distribution key. But your suggestion of splitting out the time component (as long as you don’t reduce it to one row an hour) is a great one. Distribute on that new time column. It should help queries which group by time across days. And the 1440 different times per day should distribute evenly (produce no skew).

Comment: Thanks Greg, I also wanted to check with you - when considering table distribution what should be our primary focus, is it DATA or SIZE of table. I read in the Microsoft documentation that Hash distribution is recommended for tables of size greater than 2GB

Comment: @VivekKB for small dimension tables which are joined to large distributed tables then replicated is preferred. Otherwise I would do hash distribution on all other tables if you have a good column to distribute on.

Comment: I have another query around workload groups. I'm very much confused about the parameters REQUEST_MIN_RESOURCE_GRANT_PERCENT & REQUEST_MAX_RESOURCE_GRANT_PERCENT. Hence I put forward my scenario and if possible could you please share your inputs here, please? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222020/dedicated-sql-pool-workload-management